# Understanding union all parallelism in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

**Problem Scope:**

I'm trying to understand the parallelism when using a union-all operator across date-partitioned tabled inside of BigQuery. I'm wondering if I'm understanding what's happening "under the hood" correctly.

My current approach is as follows:
+ Test a **single** query across 5, 10, 20, 30, 60 date partitions

Note: I couldn't include query as it contains some proprietary stuff :(

**Reference:**

[1,5,10 date partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxdzG.jpg)

[20, 30, 60 date partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnxp8.jpg)

**My Reasoning:**

1 date partition:
seems pretty straightforward. Not much waiting is done. Query is dominated by the aggregation/compute step.

5 date partitions:
doesn't seem like much really changes from the 1 date partition. This, to me, indicates parallelism in reads and aggregation without sacrificing much of the non-parallelizable computations.

10 date partitions:
Waiting creeps up. Still dominated by compute and read step. Also some read-skew here which I imagine is natural given more shards are being read.

20 date partitions:
A bit more waiting from before but really negligible difference.

30 date partitions:
A noticeable jump from previous query. Wait-skew is apparent and wait seems to be noticeable. There also is some write skew as well and it appears that compute step isn't dominating anymore.

60 date partitions:
Finally, waiting is really noticeable and seems to shadow read and compute. If I understand correctly, there is a jump in write-skew.

**Where I need you:**

From my experiment, it seems performance really degrades when we hit 30/60 date partitions. From my understanding, increased wait time allude to usage of all the slots available. Is there any documentation or best practices or even ways to scale up such that performance doesn't drop as we parallelize across more date partitions.

Comment: Do you have a flat-rate reservation? Or are you relying on on-demand pricing?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard From the billing page, I believe we are relying on on-demand pricing(seems like current billing for BQ relies on usage) although we would be open to look towards flat rate billing. Looking at stack-driver, it seems we have 2000 slots available which I'm not sure is a native to either pricing categories.

Comment: When you use on-demand pricing, you are capped at 2000 slots, so performance will start to degrade once you are using all of them at once. To lift the limit on parallelism, you would need to switch to a flat-rate pricing model instead. Have you [contacted sales](https://cloud.google.com/contact/)? They should be able to help you figure out which would work better for you.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Thanks for your answer. That was definitely within the scope of our plans. However, do you have any tips or tricks in terms of best practices for queries which rely on union-all parallelism and is what we are doing "Ok" in terms of working with BigQuery? Also, is there like a pre-allocated shard count before a query is executed such that in some cases, there will be waiting regardless or does big query use some sort of dynamic shard allocation to allow maximum parallelism, given sufficient resources?

Comment: Have you seen the [video from GCP Next](https://youtu.be/UueWySREWvk)? It gives an overview of slots and parallelism and might be useful to watch if you haven't seen it.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Yes, that vid was the exact motivation for the second question (seems some pre-computation is done for # shards used when doing a count on a table so if that's the case, perhaps some waiting is inevitable (I can experiment when we get our slots boosted)). Just wanted some peace of mind to ensure my thought process: dremel tree seems to scale well with parallelizable units of work (like i/o) but some inevitable overhead which should be small in non-parallelizable pieces of work (like some mixer writes) in which case unions shouldn't degrade too much given sufficient resources.

Comment: That's correct. It sounds like you have a good understanding of how the system works and how to scale a particular project (basically just by having more slots available).